# Deadlock caused by multiple `ON DELETE CASCADE` Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am experiencing a deadlock issue, caused by chain of `ON DELETE CASCADE` FKs.
The situation is the following:

Table `C` has `ON DELETE CASCADE` FK to `B`.

Table `B` has `ON DELETE CASCADE` FK to `A`.

A one or more requests comes in, resulting in the SQL Statement(s) `DELETE FROM A where A.id = @0 AND A.userId = @1`.

However, due to the cascading FKs, a massive execution plan is generated for each of the `DELETE` statements, some of the operators request `X`/`IX` locks on `B`/`C`.

When multiple delete statements try to do this at the same time, a deadlock occurs.

Is there a way to solve this without rewriting a whole bunch of delete methods(DB uses a couple of such FKs, didn't know it could come to this) to a SPs with manual deletion of related tables?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.  With the statistics and indexes we might be able to help.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/AhPXsTYyt2Dn.png This was the best I could do with Datagrip, I currently have no access to MSSMS; Plan is for the beforementioned `DELETE FROM A WHERE...` statement -on Dev DB, Peod DB runs on significantly higher capacity, in case this means there wont be a problem there

Comment: `set showplan_xml on` to output the XML query plan instead of running the query.  And post the table DDL.  Deadlock on delete is most commonly caused by missing indexes, or poor indexing design.  Ideally, the clustered PK in a target of a cascade delete should be a subset of the clustered PK in the parent table.

Comment: Please share the XML for the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com. We also need to see table *and index* definitions, as well as the full XDL for the deadlock (you can get this from a Trace or an XEvent session). Without all these pieces we can't answer this

Comment: At a guess from the rather unclear plan from DataGrip (SSMS is much better), it seems the foreign keys don't have indexes on them, so you are seeing big scans and hash joins. You *must* index all foreign keys as the leading column of an index, as otherwise a full scan is needed for every update or delete. If you have the right indexes in place then the size of the plan shouldn't matter too much as every cascade will be using the index, and all cascades happen in the same order so will not deadlock.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay. Here is the deadlock file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w64oQ4NEIxKNMrJvMcmcIKOJn2UnJRfb/view?usp=sharing

And the plan file https://drive.google.com/file/d/109tXaB64SKbEaJlNIzeN0LbwZH3_qGkr/view?usp=sharing

I had to manually edit the xml in order to hide table/index names, so if anything seems broken I am happy to correct it. I don't know if theres another way to manually obfuscate it.

Comment: SentryOne Plan Explorer can obfuscate query plans, but not deadlock graphs. Quite what could be so secret about table names is a different question....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your issue is that the foreign keys on the child tables do not have an indexes**, so every `DELETE` on the parent table needs to scan the whole child table to ensure there are no FK consistency issues. This seems to be the cause of the deadlocks.

Add the index to each child:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Parent ON Child (ParentID);
```

Or

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Parent ON Child (ParentID, SomeOtherCol);
```

**It is essential** that all primary keys and foreign keys have an index (with those columns as the leading key columns).

If you are missing an index on the foreign key then you will get locking issues on `UPDATE` and `DELETE` against the primary key of the parent table. If you are missing an index on the primary key then you will get locking issues on `INSERT` and `UPDATE` against the child table.

I note that most of your tables don't even have clustered indexes and are just heap tables, another bad idea.

You can add other columns as part of the key or as INCLUDE, but the PK or FK **must be the leading column** in the index.

You can see the effect of the index in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=84456e27d35cc4f393c52444d1edc63b).

Comment: Thank you! I thought that clustered indexes are automatically added with the addition of a PK, but this doesn't seem to be the case. I have  'Unique Indexes' being automatically added with the PKs, but no mention of clustered or non-clustered ones. What are those unique indexes, should all PKs have clustered index and all FKs a non-clustered one? Also when should I include multiple columns in an index? Sorry for the lot of questions, I went down a rabbit hole since I posted.

Comment: A primary key is by default clustered, but it doesn't have to be. Normally you would make it the clustered index, but sometimes you want something else as the clustering key. A heap table (no clustered index at all) is not usually good. FKs can be either clustered or non-clustered, it doesn't matter. Eg a many:many join table would have both FKs as a composite PK, and then you want a second non-clustered index the opposite way round. If you are viewing in SSMS, the unique indexes are just the backing indexes for the PK, it's the same thing (if they have the same name as the PK constraint).